# Rails rescue inactive or unreachable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I have the following code in Rails routing:

```
    class LegacyRedirector
      InvalidUrlError = Class.new(ActionController::RoutingError)

      def call(params, request)
        URI.parse(request.path)
      rescue URI::InvalidURIError => e
        raise InvalidUrlError.new(e.message)
      end
    end

# routes.rb
match 'a', to: redirect(LegacyRedirector.new)
```

This is for catching invaild URLs. However when I test it in browser for curl, it would still display  `URI::InvalidURIError`, not my new error class. It seems the rescue block was never reached, yet I am sure I am rescuing the correct type. How can that be?

````
URI::InvalidURIError at /twitter/typeahead-js/wikis/home[
=========================================================

> bad URI(is not URI?): "/twitter/typeahead-js/wikis/home["

lib/gitlab/routing.rb, line 31
------------------------------

``` ruby
>  31           URI.parse(request.path)
   32         rescue URI::InvalidURIError => e
   33           raise InvalidUrlError.new(e.message)
   34         end
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause could be `better_errors`.

If an error is raised in a rescue block, its `cause` would be the original error. `better_errors` displays that `cause` instead, meaning the backtrace will not be in the rescue block. This gives you the illusion that it is never rescued.

This was recently fixed, see https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors/pull/459 for more details